# How to extract variables from running ipython notebook

Tags: python, multithreading, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have created a multithreaded ipython notebook that ignored "interrupt kernel" attempts. 
I need to extract variables from it, by printing or pickling them. Is there a way to do this?

Restarting the kernel would destroy all in-memory variables.

If it is not possible, maybe there is a way to prevent it in the future, via ipython magics, for example?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do - can you please explain with some actual code, along with sample input and your expected output? The usual way of printing/saving values is to do it while the program is running - AFAIK Python doesn't have the architecture to alter code while it is executing, unlike, say, Erlang for example.

Comment: Sorry. I am indeed trying to save values from running notebook -- ipython doesn't let me to stop it, only to restart, which would mean that I lose everything in memory, so I made this question in a hope that somebody had it before.

Not sure about code example -- just any infinite loop.
I am afraid this question has more to do with ipython rather than with python.

Comment: Have you tried opening another notebook attached to the running kernel and seeing if you can access the values that way? From what I understand, this should be possible. For instance, I should be able to start an instance running on my server on an accessible port, then access that port from my desktop and have access to everything in that session. It's something I've thought about doing before, but never gotten around to it. As long as you know the kernel ID, you theoretically *should* be able to attach another notebook to it.